# Jquery Menu from hover to onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to get the drop downs to close when clicked in the body.  Everything above Jen's stuff comment is correct. The stuff after I thought would close the drop downs but instead of sliding up they are stacking infinitely.

```
$(function() {

  $('.digimeg-main-nav>li>a').on('click', function() {

    var navContentId = $(this).data('subnav');

    $('#' + navContentId).stop().slideDown({
      queue: false
    });
  });

  $('.digimeg-sub-nav>li').on('click', function() {

    $(this).stop().slideDown({
      queue: false
    });

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Jens stuff////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('#' + navContentId).stop().slideUp({
        queue: false
      });
    });

  });

  $('navContentId').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: If you'd provide your html and place the code in a working [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/) it will make it easier to help you out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7dnsoL24/#&togetherjs=aTl98MNxHi

Comment: You can see the snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/7dnsoL24/ (I had to figure out the snippet interface but I have my jquery imported properly now) You can see that on click new menus open but I can't get them to close or toggle when clicking outside.